# Error con inputs date en firefox

Tags: html, firefox, calendar, chrome

Tengo el siguiente html:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha_fin" value=""></p>
```

En chrome funciona bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en firefox tengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, firefox coloca un calendario por delante de mi calendario. ¿Como puedo solucionar esto? ¿Hay alguna forma de bloquear el calendario de firefox? ¿Es un error en mi configuración?

Comment: Para obligar al navegador firefox a usar tus estilos has probado en tu css añadir la palabra `!important` para todos los selectores que hagan referéncia a tu calendario?

Answer (score 0):

para obligar al navegador firefox a usar tus estilos has probado en tu css añadir la palabra `!important` para todos los selectores que hagan referéncia a tu calendario?